# Как поставить текст на передний план Turtle

Tags: python, turtle

Нужно, чтобы текст находился поверх остальной анимации, вот сам код. Как это реализовать и есть ли вообще такая возможность в модуле туртл?

```py
import turtle
import math

def xt(t):
    return 16 * math.sin(t) ** 3
def yt(t):
    return 13 * math.cos(t) - 5 \
           * math.cos(2 * t) - 2 * \
           math.cos(3 * t) - math.cos(4 * t)
t = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.color("pink")
turtle.write("сш я тя лю", True, align="center",font = ( "Verdana", 16, "normal" ))
turtle.colormode(255)
turtle.Screen().bgcolor(0, 0, 0)
t.speed(500)
for i in range(2550):
    t.goto((xt(i) * 20, yt(i) * 20))
    t.pencolor((255 - i) % 255, i % 255, (255 + i) // 2 % 255)
    t.goto(0, 0)

t.hideturtle()
turtle.update()
turtle.mainloop()
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как черепашка - это, по-сути, карандаш, то вариант один: каждый раз в цикле писать текст заново.

```
import turtle
import math

def xt(t):
    return 16 * math.sin(t) ** 3
def yt(t):
    return 13 * math.cos(t)     - \
            5 * math.cos(2 * t) - \
            2 * math.cos(3 * t) - \
                math.cos(4 * t)

turtle.color("pink")
turtle.colormode(255)
turtle.Screen().bgcolor(0, 0, 0)
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.Screen().tracer(2) # чтобы рисовало побыстрее

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.hideturtle()
t.speed(500)
for i in range(2550):
    t.goto((xt(i) * 20, yt(i) * 20))
    t.pencolor((255 - i) % 255, i % 255, (255 + i) // 2 % 255)
    t.home()
    turtle.write("сш я тя лю", False, align="center",font = ( "Verdana", 16, "normal" ))

turtle.update()
turtle.mainloop()
turtle.done()
```

Comment: спасибо, вообще не думал про это